# How to add a new element to a specific cell inside a table?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

```
<?php session_start() ; 
include 'databaseConnection.php' ;
$sqlCommand3 = "SELECT * FROM posts ;" ;
        $result3 = mysqli_query($conn , $sqlCommand3);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result3);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) { ?>
<tr>
  <td style="padding-left: 10px;"> 
    <?php echo $row['poster']; ?>
  </td>
  <td style="padding-left: 45px;">
    <?php echo $row['post_destination']; ?>
  </td>
  <td style="padding-left: 30px;">
    <?php echo $row['post_readyTime']; ?>
  </td>
  <td style="padding-left: 45px;"> 
    <?php  echo $row['post_numberOfPassenger'];?>
  </td>
  <td style="padding-left: 32px;">
    <?php echo $row['post_submitTime']; ?>
  </td>
  <td>
    <form action="riderJoin.php" method="post">
      <input type ="hidden" name ="id" value="<?php echo $row['post_id']; ?>" >
      <input type =submit  class="edit_btn"  name = submit value = "Join">

    </form>
  </td>

  <!--<td>
    <a href="riderPage.php?del=<?php /*echo $row['post_id'];*/ ?>" class="del_btn" id="<?php /*echo $row['post_id'];*/ ?>">Delete</a>

  </td>-->
</tr>
<?php } ?>

</table>

</div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $("td:nth-child(4):contains('5')").addClass('redWord');
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName('edit_btn');


    <?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { ?>
    var i = <?php echo $_SESSION['postId'] ; ?> - 1 ;
    $(x[i]).val('Delete').css('background-color','red').css('color','white');
    <?php }?>



</script>
```

How to add a new input (type = "submit" value="delete") with a new action (before the "join" button) whenever the $_POST['submit'] is set? I don't want to add a new input before each "join" button. Instead, I just want to add after a specific "join" button inside a cell when that specific "join" button is clicked. Also, if I click another 'join' button in other cell, a similar effect would happen too. So in the end, after clicking two "join" button, there should be only two delete button each added before the specific clicked "join" buttons. How to solve it ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: What does it mean - how to add? Insert some html button markup. What's the problem with this?

Comment: @u_mulder I want to prepend a "delete" button whenever a specific "join" button inside a cell is clicked. I couldn't just add id to the each "join" button and get it by id cuz it's displayed using database results